# Why won't my dell lattitude 5591 charge after installing ubuntu?

Tags: dell, charging

I bought a new Dell latitude 5591 and installed ubuntu on a 1 tb pcie m.2 drive. The laptop charged fine with the windows installation and also charges fine when the machine is turned off, but no longer charges when the laptop is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if your system recognize your battery, to do this type the following command in your terminal

`upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`

The /org/... path can be found with the command upower -e (--enumerate).

If your system detects battery, try next steps:

- go to BIOS (to enter the BIOS, I pressed ENTER at boot, and then F1)
- in the BIOS, go to Config, then select Disable Built-in Battery. This disables the battery completely (i.e. disconnects the battery circuit logically)
- unplug the charger
- press the power button for about 10 seconds
- plug the charger back in
- boot up

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the battery also wasn't detected by system BIOS.  I reset the battery and now it works.

Steps to reset your dell battery:

1. disconnect ac adapter and battery
2. Hold power-button for 15 seconds
3. Wait 2 minutes
4. Plug in ac adapter and boot the computer
5. shutdown the computer after the full boot process
6. Reconnect the battery

Now it works, my computer is charging and the bios is able to detect the battery

Answer (score 1):

My issue is not related. But, putting it out here,just in case it helps anyone else. So, I received a new Dell Latitude 3410 with Ubuntu 18 pre-installed. I removed Ubuntu 18 and installed Ubuntu 20, and started noticing that my battery was not charging at all. Went to BIOS (press F2 key continuously after rebooting), and observed that `OverView --> Battery --> AC Adapter` was showing `Not Installed`. `OverView --> Battery --> Battery State` was showing `Excellent`.

I know this is totally silly, but yes, this being a new laptop, the AC adapter jack was a bit tight, and the charging port had not yet fully gone in. Once, I rechecked the AC Adapter port and carefully put the adpater port fully in, the battery started charging.